# Hive Prepared Statement set Date function not working properly

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, prepared-statement

I am having hive tables and I am population data using jdbc driver by writing prepared statement queries as shown below.

```
Connection con = HiveConnectionMgr.getConnection();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            java.util.Date yourDate= null;
            try {
                yourDate = sdf.parse("2018-09-02");
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String sql ="select * from txns_fact where txndate=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            System.out.println(sql+new java.sql.Date(yourDate.getTime()));
            java.sql.Date d = new java.sql.Date(yourDate.getTime());
            ps.setDate(1, d);  //here
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); //not working
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("cameinnnnnnn");
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"--"+rs.getTimestamp(2)+"--"+rs.getString(3));
            }

            sql = "insert into table txnaggr_fact partition(txninterval=?) values('a','b','c',4,'Test')";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setDate(1, d); //here
            System.out.println("sql="+sql);

            ps.executeUpdate(); //throws exception

            System.out.println("inserted");

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

During insertion I am getting the following exception.

```
sql=insert into table txnaggr_fact partition(txninterval=?) values('a','b','c',4,'Test')

org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:57 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2018' in insert clause
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:256)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:242)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:254)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeUpdate(HiveStatement.java:406)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HivePreparedStatement.java:119)
        at com.cw.na.vos.DateTest.main(DateTest.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:57 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2018' in insert clause
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:206)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:290)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:320)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:530)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:517)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:310)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:530)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1437)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1422)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 1:57 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2018' in insert clause
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1295)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:204)
        ... 15 more
```

I am unable to understand why I am getting the exception but If I am using set String and setting the date parameter by converting it to String, Then this works. Can someone tell me how to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is Hive's Date type isn't really Java's Date type, it's in fact String type. If you look at Hive's [DateObjectInspector](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive/DateObjectInspector.java) you won't see Java's Date, rather `org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.Date`. I would suggest you to use Hadoop's Date.